What does "epic column inches" mean?
Paragraph five from this article: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/oct/13/howard-jacobson-gaza-israel-cruelty-louise-adler

You suspect the western media of propaganda when, in reality, there has been a remarkable lack of representation of life in Gaza since 7 October. I’m not sure where you were last weekend but the epic column inches devoted to the Israeli victims of 7 October does not suggest a failure to give due regard to their suffering.

I don't understand what "epic column inches" mean. I do have two guesses though.

"Epic column" refers to a specific column written last weekend, and its content was "inches", or very much, devoted to the Israeli victims.

"Epic column inches" means many columns were written, and "inches" in this instance is referring to the voluminous columns.


I have never seen the word "inches" placed and used this way, so a explanation would be nice.

Column inches is an idiom referring to the length of columns of text in a newspaper.
Epic implies that there were a large number of inches (an epic is a long poem or story.)

Yes! I only see two other hits on that phrase, one from 2005 (https://www.thetimes.com/article/and-its-goodnight-to-mass-rituals-hbz65g53fnc) and the other from 2014 (https://cricketyorkshire.com/bad-behaviour-gone-too-far/). It seems to be a kind of hyperbole.

The kids these days may not be aware that newspaper columns were once typically found printed as columns of text on physical pieces of paper.

@TaliesinMerlin It's not a phrase. It's writing. Why do people so often think that everything has already been written and can be found via google?

Columns of text are still familiar even nowadays in the age of digital media. But the phrase "column inches" is jargon which might well not be familiar to the layperson.

@TaliesinMerlin Google NGram Viewer shows the use "column inches" rose sharply in the 1920s and has been tailing off since. Also see Farlex, particularly used for advertising space.

@Lambie It's a phrase. Why do people think that when I say "phrase" I mean idiom and not noun phrase, which isn't a set expression but can be understood through finding similar instances of use?

@TaliesinMerlin I think the point being made is that "large music book" would be understood as a [large] [music book] without searching if [large music book] was an existing phrase. Similarly [epic] is being used to mean "large or impressive". Like "epic journey", "epic jump", "epic piece of toast"

"Idiom" might be the wrong word. "Column inches" is a unit of measure in the newspaper world (which still exists...) just as it is a unit of measure when speaking of barometric pressure. It's most often used to define the price of advertising where story length is more often defined by word count. (However, good editors and writers, knowing the typography of the newspaper, can easily convert.) Here it's used to allegorically underscore journalism. And "Epic" isn't just a synonym of large, it carries emotion. The writer was trying to convey the coverage was unusually, even unreasonably large.

@JBH: “idiom” seems a pretty accurate description of “column inches” — it’s a well-established phrase whose usual meaning in context isn’t obvious just from the meanings of its components.  (It’s transparent once explained, but a reader could reasonably know the meanings of “column” and “inches” but not immediately understand “column inches”.)  On the other hand “epic column inches” as a whole isn’t an established idiom: its meaning is entirely compositional based on the individual meanings of “epic” and “column inches”.

Specifically, many writers in that industry are paid by the column-inch (where in other fields they might be paid by the word, page, or something else). That's the context that the term escaped from — and as such, it carries a bit of a "quantity over quality" vibe even without the help of "epic".

@hobbs If “paid by the column-inch”, imagine the pressure the writers must put on the people in charge of formatting typography. :-)

I worked for a print newspaper in the early 2000s, and my assignments were always given in column inches. It wasn't just for advertising -- it was just how everything was measured, because that's what ultimately mattered for layout. (I wasn't paid per column-inch, but I was always told to write a bit more than the column-inches specified. It's easy for the layout editor to chop off a few sentences or paragraphs, but harder to have to add them.) That said, I definitely agree this is industry jargon that escaped into the article. I doubt I'd know the term if I hadn't worked in the biz.

@yshavit: At least in the days of print newspapers in the UK, it was a pretty widely-understood term, not just industry jargon.  Looking at ngrams suggests in US English its frequency peaked in the ’50s and fell off thereafter, whereas in the UK it kept rising and peaked only around 2005.
